# Jenkins - build all submodules reports to Sonar with one job

Tags: java, maven, build, module, sonarqube

We've got a lot of submodules in our company. We want to add Sonar to check our code quality and so on. If we start the build from the top of our project the build runs without failures and creates reports for sonar.

Our architecture is like:

```
<Project>
   <module1>
   <module2>
   <module3>
       .
       .
       .
       .
   <moduleX>
```

But the problem is, if one of the submodules failes the whole build won't succeed.

Now the question:
is it possible building and creating sonar reports for every module without creating one jenkins-jobs for every one module?

Comment: You want all of your modules to be separate projects in sonar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is NO.

Long answer: if you put all your projects inside a top level project and run a Sonar analysis on it, obviously if a project fails then the Sonar build stops. The reason is that Sonar thinks that you are analysing a single project (because of the top level POM you created with the "module" list). So this is normal that if a project analysis fails at some point, then Sonar don't go further in the analysis.

So yes: you have to define 1 Jenkins job per project (or maybe there's some Jenkins plugin that allows you to apply a job configuration to a set of repositories - who knows, there are so many plugins out there).

Note that Jenkins can also be configured thanks to Groovy scripts: this can save time if you know how to do it (you can have a look at the following script that we wrote for a migration of our Sonar Jenkins Plugin => http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Migration+from+Jenkins+Sonar+Plugin+1.6+to+1.8).

Comment: OK, I'll have a look on that. So it is not possible to tell jenkins somithing like: "Take this pom, create a report just for those submodules that have been built successfully"?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but as I said if 1 module fails, then the whole analysis will stop. And it does not meet what you want to achieve = having an analysis for each one of your **project** (vs. 1 single analysis for all your code base)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe we'll refactor our project architecture to handle the report creating some other way.